# Apache version 2.1 - What is the deal?

Tags: apache

I've been given an assignment to confiure apache v2.1 (on any platform) as a reverse proxy.

Installing Apache2 on Ubuntu gave me version 2.2, but I can't find reference to a version 2.1 for download anywhere. I've seen references to v2.1 in the documentation but under 2.2.

Is it possible to get v2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache 2.1 was the development version for Apache 2.2. So Apache 2.1 and 2.2 are essentially the same.
AFAIK, odd number releases are development version, and even numbered are production versions (So 2.3 is the current "development", and will become 2.4 is due time).

Why anyone would ask you to specifically install this version, I do not know, but unless you have a **very** good reason to do otherwise, just install the latest version.

Comment: I thought it would be something along these lines. I'm hoping that by asking for version 2.1, they were just trying to catch me out and that using 2.2 won't score me down.